# Why do I have 98 lines instead of 99?

Tags: java

I have a directory named json which contains 99 json files.

The files are named: sentiment_i.json where i is an incremental integer starting from 1.

I wrote some code to read some content from each of these files and write said content in a txt file with one line for each json file.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, IOException, ParseException {

        String type ="";
        ArrayList<String> sentiment = new ArrayList<String>();

        int i= 1;
        double score = 0;

        File dir = new File("json");
        File[] directoryListing = dir.listFiles();
        JSONObject jsonObject;

        if (directoryListing != null) {
            for (File child : directoryListing) {
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

                try {
                    jsonObject  = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("json/sentiment_"+i+".json"));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    i++;
                    continue;
                }

                JSONObject doc = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("docSentiment"); // get the nested object first
                type = (String)doc.get("type"); // get a string from the nested object

                // CODICE PER PRENDERE ANCHE LO SCORE
                if (!(type.equals("neutral"))){
                    score = (double) doc.get("score");
                } else score = 0;

                sentiment.add(type+";"+score);
                i++;
            }
        }

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("sentiment.txt");
        for(String value: sentiment)
            out.println(value);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get 98 lines in my txt file even if there are 99 json files in the directory.

I've been trying to find the bug for an hour now but I'm going nuts!

Hope you can help me, thanks.

**EDIT: Woah the downvotes :(**

Anyway, maybe I was not clear. The point has never been catching and dealing with the missing file!

Also

```
jsonObject  = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader(child))
```

in my case is not useful at all and let me explain why.

In the json folder, as stated, there json files named like this: "sentiment_1", "sentiment_2" and so on.

In the folder there are let's say 1000 of these but not every number from 1 to 1000 is there.

If you rely on FileReader(child), in the for loop the files are not read in the correct order (1,2,3,4...)!

This happens because for the sorting order in the folder, for example 10 comes before than 2 because the order is 1,10,2,3,4....

So, as clearly the downvoters didn't understand at all, the problem is not that easy at it seems.

It's not about a simple loop problem lol.

Comment: Catching and ignoring the `FileNotFoundException` is not a good idea.

Comment: Relying on FileNotFoundException is relatively expensive. You should just do a file exists check. That saves your program making a stacktrace and everything every time a thing is missed.

Comment: can you show the value of directoryListing and i ?

Comment: in the try/catch you're adding +1 to `i` and then you do it again. Have you checked that?

Comment: @tumisma he is adding +1 to i, but he don't add again, he skip to the next iteration with `continue`

Answer (score 1):

Because of this block of code:

```
try {
    jsonObject  = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("json/sentiment_"+i+".json"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    i++;
    continue;
}
```

Which is omitting the error from you, use this instead:

```
try {
    jsonObject  = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("json/sentiment_"+i+".json"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a missformatted json file name:

```
try {
    jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("json/sentiment_"+i+".json"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    i++;
    continue;
}
```

This block of code tells that, if a file is not found, it is just ignored without any console feedback.

Replace by :

```
try {
    jsonObject  = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("json/sentiment_"+i+".json"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Missing json file: " +  e.getMessage());
    i++;
    continue;
}
```

You will have an idea about what is going on.

#### A better solution

Currently you are looping through files but you never use the current iteration, you are using an `i` variable. A `FileReader` can be instanciated with a `File` instead of the file path as a string:

```
try {
    jsonObject  = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader(child));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Missing json file: " +  e.getMessage());
    i++;
    continue;
}
```

Comment: The better solution but has a compilation error: The resource type JSONParser does not implement java.lang.AutoCloseable. 

The first solution works exactly as my code, giving only 98 lines instead of 99!

Comment: Woops, sorry, i though it was Autoclosable, i fixed it. I'm not saying the first module will output you 99 line, i said it will warn about a missnamed file, watch at your console when executing the code, you'll be warned about a 'file not found'